# Continue running middle relay with Vidalia 0.2.21 (Tor 2.4.23)?

Tags: relays, windows, vidalia, middle

The Vidalia bundles are still advertised in the [TBB3 FAQ](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/TorBrowserBundle3FAQ#HowdoIconfigureTorasarelayorbridge), but [no longer available to download](https://www.torproject.org/download/download.html.en). What should Windows users who want to run a **middle relay** do? Conversely, should operators stop running relay that were set up with the last downloadable `vidalia-relay-bundle-0.2.4.23-0.2.21.exe`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vidalia is no longer officially supported. I believe that any remaining references to Vidalia are accidental or historical. If you want to run a relay on Windows, just download the latest tor browser bundle. The bundle includes the latest stable version of tor. Edit your torrc (local inside the downloaded bundle directory) as you normally would to set yourself up as a relay.

However, since relays are meant to be up for long periods of time, have you considered switching to linux? Mandatory Windows restarts every week mean unnecessary downtime for your relay. Doing a fresh minimal install of debian is easy and will probably be better for relay stability. If you don't want to wipe your laptop, dual booting would also be a reasonable choice.

Comment: `Edit your torrc (local inside the downloaded bundle directory) [...]` Ah, OK, thanks!

`[...] considered switching to linux?` Yes, but that's not an option for the machine I can run the relay on.

Answer (score 2):

Any reference to Vidalia that you can still find is a mistake, please either fix it by editing the Wiki or file a bug on [the bug Tracker](https://trac.torproject.org).